# php - How can I identify refresh from any other type page change

Tags: php, page-refresh, hitcounter

I am using php code to create and update an SQL database which I, in turn, use to populate an on-screen page counter (see code snippet below).  How can I differentiate a page refresh from any other url change so as not to add to my counter every time the page is refreshed?  I want to do this without putting cookies on my user's desktop.  Thanks in advance for your help.

```
include("incPHP1.inc");
$cxn=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database)
    or die ("Couldn't connect to the server.");
$result = mysqli_query($cxn, "SELECT * FROM visitors");
$counter = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$views = $counter;
```

Cosmin:

I copied the code as you have written it into the first line of my php code (see first attempt code below).  It did not work in either IE11 or Firefox 55.0.3.  In both cases, I got an error message (Fatal error: Function name must be a string in D:\InetPub\vhosts\rlcdev.com\httpdocs\index.php on line 2) and no output.  I removed the initial $session_name(); command line and left it out (see second attempt code below).  This was because I understand that the $session_start(); command must be the first line after the

First Attempt:

```
<?php
$session_name();
$session_start();
$_SESSION['refresh'] = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL'])  && $_SERVER

['HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL'] === 'max-age=0';
if($_SESSION['refresh'])
{
            echo ("<SCRIPT>alert ( 'Page has been refreshed, The AJAX call was not made');</SCRIPT>");
}
else
{
                echo ("<SCRIPT>alert ( 'This is a non-refresh reload' );</SCRIPT>");
}
```

Second Attempt:

```
<?php
$session_start();
$_SESSION['refresh'] = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL'])  && $_SERVER

['HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL'] === 'max-age=0';
if($_SESSION['refresh'])
{
            echo ("<SCRIPT>alert ( 'Page has been refreshed, The AJAX call was not made');</SCRIPT>");
}
else
{
                echo ("<SCRIPT>alert ( 'This is a non-refresh reload' );</SCRIPT>");
}
```

Comment: Try dumping the CGI environment variables to see if there's one that you can test on. http://php.net/reserved.variables.server

Comment: use cookie? you could store the time in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Use cookies.

In your case set a cookie with name you prefer and value you prefer (already_visited = 1) with lifetime validity (7 years). Then you can check if this cookie is sent by browser. If browser has sent the cookie value then it is a refresh else if the cookie value is not sent by browser then it is a first time visit.

Note: This technique is dependent on cookies, you can only track if the cookies are accepted in browser. There is no option to check this if cookies are disabled in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method:
use a flag variable

```
$refresh = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL'])  && $_SERVER['HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL'] === 'max-age=0';
if($refresh)
{
  echo ("<SCRIPT>alert ( 'Page has been refreshed, The AJAX call was not made');</SCRIPT>");
}
 else
     {
      echo ("<SCRIPT>alert ( 'This is a non-refresh reload' );</SCRIPT>");
     }
```

Comment: Hi, yes that was my fault as it was just a redundant check for the session name which obviously was nonexistent in your case (the session being initialized at this stage). Check out the edit

Comment: Drop the whole session handling and $_SESSION variable ( my bad :| )

Comment: And about the session_start function (FYI): it has to be called before sending any output (i.e echo or print) to the browser but the session_name function can be called (and is a good practice to be called) before the session_start function in order to set a custom name for the your active session, thus reducing penetration risks. To be fair I induced you in error by leaving the session_name function without a parameter.

Comment: Just noticed that in IE and Edge it is not recognizing refreshes. Works fine in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: I would say that your best bet for IE and Edge would be to use a case scenario to detect the browser and if it finds IE then use a js snippet to check for page refresh and post a flag to your php, else use the above.

Comment: Cosmin - I still have to use the $session_start(); statement at the very beginning of my php script - right?  That would be immediately before the updated code.  I tried it that way in bot IE11 and Foxfire and got the same error message.

Comment: No, don't use session_start anymore since as far as I can tell from your code you are not doing session handling in your project. Just use the code from the edited answer and it will work just fine in Chrome and Firefox. Check my comments above for a proposed solution for IE. It should work as in the test link I posted :  microsol.eu/refresh.php

Answer (score 0):

Still didn't work, Cosmin.  I've decided to go a different way, using a SQL database, timer and Ajax calls to determine if the call is a refresh or new.  It'll help with some other issues I'm trying to address.  Thanks for all the help.